# How to configure XML-config for XLSReader

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jxls

I'm using the `org.jxls:jxls-reader` to read some data from an excel-sheet.
The rows start at excel row 20 and should be read until the next row is empty.
But I have problems to get the xml-config configured right to read the rows.

Every following row after the first returns a `null` value.

I've tried to understand the `departmentdata.xls` provided in 
http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html but i can't get it right.

Some insights for the configuration would be appreciated.

My Code in `ExcelUploadController`:

```
            InputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile)

            XLSReader reader = ReaderBuilder.buildFromXML(xmlInputStream);

            InputStream xlsInputStream = dataFile.getInputStream();

            DocumentDetailPosition documentDetailPosition = new DocumentDetailPosition();

            List<DocumentDetailPosition> documentDetailPositions = new ArrayList<>();

            Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<>();

            beans.put("documentDetailPosition", documentDetailPosition);

            beans.put("documentDetailPositions", documentDetailPositions);

            XLSReadStatus status = reader.read(xlsInputStream, beans)
```

My `xml-Config`:

```
   <workbook>
       <worksheet name="worksheet1">
        <section startRow="0" endRow="19"/>
            <loop startRow="19" endRow="29" items="documentDetailPositions" var="documentDetailPosition" varType="pl.fissst.crm.esales.pojo.DocumentDetailPosition">
               <section startRow="19" endRow="29">
                   <mapping row="19" col="0" type="java.lang.Integer">documentDetailPosition.posProductNo</mapping>
                   <mapping row="19" col="1" type="java.lang.Integer">documentDetailPosition.quantity</mapping>
                   <mapping row="19" col="3"  type="java.util.Date">documentDetailPosition.requestDate</mapping>
               </section>
               <loopbreakcondition>
                   <rowcheck offset="0"/>
                   <cellcheck offset="0"></cellcheck>
               </loopbreakcondition>
           </loop>
       </worksheet>
    </workbook>
```

when the values of DocumentDetail get printed the log shows:

```
INFO  885744 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - 1234567
INFO  885744 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - 5 
INFO  885746 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - Thu Jan 03 00:00:00 CET 2019 

INFO  885746 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - null 
INFO  885746 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - null 
INFO  885746 g.a.c.p.f.c.e.ExcelUploadController - null
```

Expected behavior: Reading all rows

Actual Result: Reading first row and then everything is `null`

Comment: Have you checked this example from `jxls-reader` test https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-reader/src/master/src/test/java/org/jxls/reader/ReaderBuilderTest.java ?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop tag, startRow and endRow must be the same.
In your loopbreakcondition, the cellcheck tag goes inside the rowcheck tag.

And I'm not sure if the mapping works with something different than strings